# Python 3. Understand multiple for loops (indention)

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a list and I used a for loop and the code is in this link:
[Python For Loop code. (2 for loops in one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pFDY.jpg)

What would the result of 3 for loops look like when the last two loops are indented below each other. [Here is an example of what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLUgs.jpg)I also want an explanation to this as well.The explanation that I am looking for is similar to the explanation in the first link above.
The code for Image 2 is:

```
hugehairypants = ['huge', 'hairy', 'pants']
for i in hugehairypants:
    print(i)
    for j in hugehairypants:
        print(j)
        for f in hugehairypants:
            print(f)
```

(EDIT: I think I understand it now)
What if you have four for loops????????????????????????
For example:

```
hugehairypants = ['huge', 'hairy', 'pants']
for i in hugehairypants:
    print(i)
    for j in hugehairypants:
        print(j)
        for f in hugehairypants:
            print(f)
            for z in hugehairypants:
                print(z)
```

Comment: Best way to find out would be to run it yourself :-)

Comment: I did run it myself. But I don't understand it theoretically. @Idanmel

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as (formatted) text and not as images.

Comment: Walk through it by hand - pretend you are the computer and execute each step in order, use pencil and paper to keep track- sometimes doing that is enlightening

Answer (score 0):

This code would return the output

```
huge
huge
huge
hairy
pants
hairy
huge
hairy
pants
pants
huge
hairy
pants
hairy
huge
huge
hairy
pants
hairy
huge
hairy
pants
pants
huge
hairy
pants
pants
huge
huge
hairy
pants
hairy
huge
hairy
pants
pants
huge
hairy
pants
```

What a mouthful. Anyway, in essence, what you're doing is saying "for each of the elements (i) in hugehairypants, print the element (i), and for each of the elements (j)in hugehairypants print the element (j) and for each of the lements (f) in hugehairypants print the element (f).

Again, that's a huge mouthful. It might help to look at like this, as a tree of sorts.

```
For each element (i) in huge hairy pants
|
|-> Print the element i
|--> For each element (j) in huge hairy pants
|
|---> Print the element j
|---> For each element (f) in huge hairy pants
|
|----> Print the element f
```

Comment: But which for loop (i,j or f) printed what?

Comment: You can easily visualize this by changing your print statement from print(i) to print(i, "First loop") and so on.

Comment: This is what I understand: In the beginning (i) prints out huge , (j) prints out huge , (f) prints out huge, hairy and pants. But I don't understand what happens after.

Comment: After that, the second loop continues. You will get "hairy" after that. Then the third loop starts again and you will get "huge hairy pants". Then the second loop continues and so on. Once that finishes, the first loop will continue and the second loop will start again.

Comment: It sounds like "Rocket Science". This image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pFDY.jpg   explained two for loops in an easy way, but then when I tried 3 for loops the logic did not sound right.

Answer (score 0):

I re-wrote the code for better understanding the output:

1. Step-1: The for loop with i gets executed and selects 'huge'
2. Step-2:The for loop with j gets executed and selects 'huge'
3. Step-3: The for
   loop with f gets executed until all 3 elements are printed out
   namely 'huge', 'hairy', 'pants'

Then, The loop goes back to J and selects hairy and returns to' step-3'and continues until all elements under for loop i are complete!

```js
ughhairypants = ['huge', 'hairy', 'pants']
for i in hughhairypants:
    print('I-'+i)
    for j in hughhairypants:
        print('J-'+j)
        for f in hughhairypants:
            print('F-'+f)
```

```js
Output:
I-huge
J-huge
F-huge
F-hairy
F-pants
J-hairy
F-huge
F-hairy
F-pants
J-pants
F-huge
F-hairy
F-pants
I-hairy
J-huge
F-huge
F-hairy
F-pants
J-hairy
F-huge
F-hairy
F-pants
J-pants
F-huge
F-hairy
F-pants
I-pants
J-huge
F-huge
F-hairy
F-pants
J-hairy
F-huge
F-hairy
F-pants
J-pants
F-huge
F-hairy
F-pants
```

Comment: So does this mean that (i) prints out after (j) and (f) are done.

Comment: Correct, Refer the output

Answer (score 0):

*But which for loop (i,j or f) printed what?*

```
i starts with `huge`
j starts with `huge`
f loops `huge, hairy, pants`
j jumps to `hairy`
f loops `huge, hairy, pants`
j jumps to `pants`
f loops `huge, hairy, pants`
i jumps to `hairy`
j starts with `huge`
f loops `huge, hairy, pants`
j jumps to `hairy`
f loops `huge, hairy, pants`
j jumps to `pants`
f loops `huge, hairy, pants`
i jumps to `pants`
j starts with `huge`
f loops `huge, hairy, pants`
j jumps to `hairy`
f loops `huge, hairy, pants`
j jumps to `pants`
f loops `huge, hairy, pants`
loop end
```

I hope this is useful :)

Comment: Very Useful. Tanks . I mean Thanks

Comment: @Faraz4567 Don't forget to accept the answer if you find it useful =)

Comment: @Faraz4567 On the left of the answer, under the votes there is a tick, you click on it to accept the answer